# Julia: Using split to construct string arrays with multiple columns

Tags: string, split, julia

I have a tuple which contains two pieces of information separated by `#` that looks like `x = ("aa#b", "a#c", "a#d")`. I can use a comprehension to transform this data into an array in the following way `[split(x[i], "#")[j] for i in 1:length(x), j in 1:2]`.

However, this seems inefficient since I am effectively running the split command twice. Is there a preferred way of handling this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite it being an old question, here it is my proposed solution

```
String.(reduce(hcat,split.(a,'#')))
```

I checked with the `@time` operator. Compared with the list comprehension proposed by Alexander, which takes `0.042378 seconds (90.93 k allocations: 4.330 MiB)`,
the amount of time required for the same operation with the proposed solution is `0.000028 seconds (34 allocations: 1.500 KiB)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
function hashsplit(x)
       out = Array{SubString{String},2}(2,length(x))
       for (ind,j) in enumerate(x)
           out[:,ind] = split(j,"#")
       end
       return out
end
```

Should be faster. Else a simple way with a list comprehension would be

`[(split(x[i], "#")...) for i in eachindex(x)]` (for a vector of tuples)

`cat(2,ans...)` or `reduce(hcat, ans)` if you want a matrix.